# ¿Cúal es la diferencia entre base_url() y site_url()? en CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy trabajando con CodeIgniter 4 y para URL Helper vi que se puede usar `base_url()` o `site_url()`, Actualmente uso base_url() para llamar los controladores y los recursos, las dudas que tengo son:

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre `base_url()` y `site_url()`?

¿Cuando usar una función y cuando la otra?

Answer (score 1):

La diferencia es que site_url incluye "index.php" y base_url no.
Entonces para hacer el código mas portable los recursos css, js e imagenes deberías usar base_url y para crear links en vistas site_url.

Posiblemente no veas la diferencia cuando usas codeigniter con urls basadas en segmentos en lugar de "query strings".

Comment: Ha que te refieres con el código más portable con base_url()? y que site_url() no lo hace?

Comment: Me refiero a que puedes dejar de usar urls basadas en segmentos sin hacer modificaciones, en cambio si no colocas correctamente en que lugar usar base_url y site_url entonces tendrás que modificar. Tampoco veo motivos para dejar de usar url con segmentos... sería un por las dudas...